# How to set the bit depth of .wav file through Windows API? (C#)

Tags: c#, winapi, audio, audio-recording, sample-rate

I'm recording sound from my Microphone, using the `mciSendString()` API function. My code is very similar to the code which is written in this link: http://blog.hansentech.com/mhblog_2011_02_26.html

Unfortunately, when I'm listening to the output record (I'm saving the output in .wav file) I can hear noises which interfering to listen to the record itself.

I searched about this problem on the internet and I found this question, which has been asked in this website in the past. (link: [Noise reduction and compression in streaming audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000642/noise-reduction-and-compression-in-streaming-audio))
From this link, I'm understood that the problem is the bit depth (8 bits). I also understood that if I will change the bit depth to 16 bits, the problem should be solved.

Does anybody know how can I change the bit depth of my records through API Functions? Which function can do this work?

Comment: Any idea how to enhance the quality in C#? The references listed below is for C.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want to send a [setaudio command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798662%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the proper parameters.

You'll probably want to experiment with the *algorithm*, *bitspersample*, *bytespersec*, and *quality* values.

See also [MCI_SETAUDIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Though it's been a while I believe you can specify the sampling rate with the [SetAudio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798662%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command.