# How to compress large MP3 files to reduce their size and sound quality in VB.NET or VB?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, audio, compression, mp3

How to compress large mp3 files :

I want if i have a 5 mb files then it can be converted to 1mb or low ...so that the high beats and music would be very low.

i want the coding for that in vb or vb.net ?

Answer (score 3):

**[MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) is *already* a compressed format. It's unlikely that if the files are already in MP3 format that you will be able to compress them any further without reducing their sound quality/bit rate.**

Even using a different encoder, you will not be able to achieve a smaller file size because the MP3 compression method is standardized across all implementations. If your current files happen to be constant bit rate (CBR), you could look into converting them to a [variable bit rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_bitrate) (VBR), which will shave a small percentage off the total size, but at the loss of some quality and with the risk of introducing some audible distortion. The amount that distortion will be disruptive depends on the individual; some can notice distortion even at 128 kbps, but you really shouldn't ever go any lower than 96 kpbs.

If you're just looking to compress some WAV files to MP3 format, you could check out this [sample project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor.aspx). I realize that it's in C#, but that should be relatively straightforward to [convert](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to VB.NET.

You should also check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203254/whats-the-best-audio-compression-library-for-net) regarding compression libraries available for the .NET Framework (C# and VB.NET).

Doing this in VB6 (the pre-.NET version) is going to be extremely difficult, and probably not worth the trouble if you're willing to consider a VB.NET-targeted solution.